# Why is the D+P fusion reaction not considered for large-scale power production?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion, nuclear-engineering

I know that D+D (fusion of deuterium + deuterium nuclei) as well as D+T (fusion of deuterium and tritium nuclei) are the reactions most commonly considered for large-scale power production. Why not D+P (fusion of deuterium and hydrogen/proton nuclei)?

Comment: Welcome to PhysicsSE! For the sake of readability, it might be helpful to specify that P, D, and T stand for protium (or proton), deuterium, and tritium, respectively.

Comment: Have you checked the cross sections? D(p,g)3He has a cross section that peaks at about 10 microbarns (at nearly 10MeV). D-D is about 0.2 barns at 1MeV, and D-T is 5 barns at 0.1MeV. Which is easier?

Comment: Also, D+P emits a gamma photon, which isn't easy to extract useful energy from. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain_reaction#The_proton%E2%80%93proton_chain_reaction  Also see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/NucEne/fusion.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've made the recommended changes to the question. The differences in cross sections and reaction products are good answers.

Comment: @PM2Ring Well, to be fair, D-T fusion emits a pretty high-energy neutron instead, which also isn't the best thing for energy extraction.

Comment: @probably_someone Very true, and they both have an annoying tendency to make the matter in the vicinity radioactive. That's why I like proton + boron fusion, it's aneutronic (apart from pesky side reactions), and the energy is in the KE of alpha particles, which can be braked electromagnetically. It's a shame that the activation energy is so high.

Comment: "It's a shame that the activation energy is so high" - and the reaction rate/energy density so low. Those 4 orders of magnitude are not to be taken lightly.